# Spring Security SAML - Response.isSigned = false

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0, adfs2.0, spring-saml

When asking if my assertion is signed it always returns false, making it hard to do a second validation after the SP filter finish. My IDP is ADFS 2.0 and I have tried to sign the entire samlresponse and only the assertion, but with the same result.

We want to get the assertion out of our ticket in the web application that is protected by the spring SP module. So when the user is authenticated we want to forward our assertion to a service that will validate it and do something if it is a valid assertion. In this service we do not want Spring security and the spring SP. We simply want the assertion forwarded and verified with openSaml library.

Our problem is that when we got the assertion out of Spring sec and forwarded to our service, validation is started with the following line, which always return false:

```
assertion.isSigned()
```

The above line of code is derived from:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
SAMLCredential credential = (SAMLCredential) authentication.getCredentials();
credential.getAuthenticationAssertion().isSigned();
```

This also generates 'false' when called in our top tier webapp.

Overriding the SAMLAuthenticationProvider adding the above code yields 'false' as well.

If we add following code snippet to our webapp: 
        Configuration.getMarshallerFactory().getMarshaller(credential.getAuthenticationAssertion());
marshaller.marshall(credential.getAuthenticationAssertion());

And then run the

```
assertion.isSigned();
```

We get 'true' as a response.

We're using spring-security-saml2-core version 1.0.1.RELEASE.

Logs:

```
10:07:19,413 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-3) Verifying issuer of the Response
10:07:19,414 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-3) Verifying signature
10:07:19,417 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-3) Processing Bearer subject confirmation
10:07:19,418 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-3) Verifying received AuthnContext org.opensaml.saml2.core.impl.AuthnContextImpl@3efbe08d against requested null
10:07:19,418 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-3) Validation of authentication statement in assertion _79ec0857-148d-49ca-8df4-25e685fdc5b9 was successful
10:07:19,422 INFO  [org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-3) AuthNResponse;SUCCESS;172.172.176.103;IAMDemoAppADFS;https://ADFSdomain.test.se/adfs/services/trust;XXX;;
10:07:19,422 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-3) Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.springframework.security.providers.ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken@2cb1c6f2: Principal: XXX; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Not granted any authorities
```

Here is our SAML response:

```
<samlp:Response Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified"
   Destination="https://domain.test.se:8443/IAMDemoAppADFS/saml/SSO"
   ID="_a97d2515-6160-4370-8e85-a34143a1e2fb" InResponseTo="a3jdaigh6671c3g5464d3ff472jffdd"
   IssueInstant="2015-10-28T09:52:34.745Z" Version="2.0"
   xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://ADFSdomain.test.se/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
    <samlp:Status><samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/></samlp:Status>
    <Assertion ID="_574cd222-ec33-4f3d-b77b-a3ab2f16d33d" IssueInstant="2015-10-28T09:52:34.745Z"
      Version="2.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <Issuer>https://ADFSdomain.test.se/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
        <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                <Reference URI="#_574cd222-ec33-4f3d-b77b-a3ab2f16d33d">
                    <Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                    <DigestValue>gk/c0lTTLw8zXdKuvkZi48eY4sA=</DigestValue>
                </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue>kU7WfGIEIQul40i9jObZ2uyb0rnJaEr2n2bBI6E/IS8Dr52quUR8nrMG5jwmGFxgdD63odpo4605SmQVlPKxOAD2GbIOSzgNDG8u/axH8JEEAhzfC5CGfE6i775WkkZ1+LsOrmrWCAJnXjejo/Zrg6z7rSi/USgeB4TmxipwF7twMunnNFKgaPntzv3dVAQjc+zglCR0A3QQwo1orM14mFcrcYlsD6sIGWd1LmumgScWE6iNt5Fif/hPirtcF0K0YpNBPbhiDwxpPZ8NgAZIjliZU8b5Qem6Vi50ysH9lj57r7hMmUD9IjgHS1wpOfZuII2if+BcddUp7aqA+GWmw7Fw==</SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
                <ds:X509Data xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </KeyInfo>
        </Signature>
        <Subject>
            <NameID>XXX</NameID>
            <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="a3jdaigh6671c3g5464d3ff472jffdd"
            NotOnOrAfter="2015-10-28T09:57:34.745Z"
            Recipient="https://domain.test.se:8443/IAMDemoAppADFS/saml/SSO"/></SubjectConfirmation>
        </Subject>
        <Conditions NotBefore="2015-10-28T09:52:34.745Z" NotOnOrAfter="2015-10-28T09:53:34.745Z">
            <AudienceRestriction>
                <Audience>IAMDemoAppADFS</Audience>
            </AudienceRestriction>
        </Conditions>
        <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2015-10-28T09:52:34.558Z"
         SessionIndex="_574cd222-ec33-4f3d-b77b-a3ab2f16d33d">
            <AuthnContext>
                <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:federation:authentication:windows</AuthnContextClassRef>
            </AuthnContext>
        </AuthnStatement>
    </Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `releaseDOM`to false in `WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl`. This use-case is documented in [the manual with additional details](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-sso.html#configuration-authentication-assertion) - it doesn't explicitly state that the signature will be removed by default, but it's likely the case.